# Char to static_cast<int> works but char[7] to static_cast doesn't

Tags: c++, string, char, static-cast

I am working on a project for class that wants me to convert a string of letters to numbers, I did not use switch statements because that would be dumb and too long, so I made the following program. However, the problem with it is that I can only do one letter at a time due to it being a char and the `static_cast<int>(phrase)` will not work if I try to do this: `char phrase[7];` it will give me 3 errors (I cant remember what they are at this moment, I will edit later today to include errors). I can't use certain code as well, like stoi and atoi as we have not gone over them in my textbook yet. So if you can give multiple different takes on this problem it would be greatly appreciated! Thank you! Also, if you can make sure the code would works with my program that would be even better! I left the `char phrase[7]` in the code so if you want to copy and paste to see the errors you can! The assignment is to have the user enter as many letters as they want and return it to them as 123-1234 as the program will only take the first 7 letters (if you can also figure out how to break up the word to allow the dash (-) to be in between that would be cool too.)

Edit:
To make telephone numbers easier to remember, some companies use letters to show their telephone number.  For example, using letters, the telephone number 438-5626 can be shown as GET LOAN.  In some cases, to make a telephone number meaningful, companies might use more than seven letters.  For example, 225-5466 can be displayed as CALL HOME, which uses eight letters.  Write a program that prompts the user to enter a telephone number expressed in letters and outputs the corresponding telephone number in digits.  If the user enters more than seven letters, then process only the first seven letters.  Also output the – (hyphen) after the third digit.  Allow the user to use both upper case and lowercase letters as well as spaces between words. The special characters – (hyphen) represents the number 1 and the _ (underscore) represents the number zero.  Moreover, your program should process as many telephone numbers as the user wants.
ERRORS:

1. invalid type conversion
2. argument of type "char *" is incompatible with parameter of type "int"
3. expression must be a modifiable Ivalue

   ```
       #include <iostream>
   #include <string>
   #include <cctype>

   using namespace std;

   int main()
   {
   char phrase[7];
   char letter;
   int digit;
   int num = 0;

   cout << "Enter Y/y to convert a telephone number from letters to digits" 
   << endl;
   cout << "Enter any other key to terminate the program." << endl;
   cin >> letter;

   while (letter == 'Y' || letter == 'y')
   {
    cout << "Enter a telephone number using 7 or more letters" << endl;
    cout << "for Prefix and number, only the first 7 letters are used." << endl;
    cout << "and dashes '-' are ZEROES, underscores '_' are ONES" << endl;
    cout << "ALL OTHER SYMBOLS ARE ignored." << endl;
    cout << "-->: ";
    cin >> phrase;
    cout << endl;

    phrase = toupper(phrase);
    num = static_cast<int>(phrase) - static_cast<int>('A');

    if (0 <= num && num < 26)
    {
        digit = (num / 3) + 2;

        if (((num / 3 == 6) || (num / 3 == 7)) && (num % 3 == 0))
            digit = digit - 1;

        if (digit > 9)
            digit = 9;

            cout << "The corresponding telephone number is: " << digit << endl;

            cout << "To process another telephone number, enter Y/y" << endl;
            cout << "Enter any other key to terminate the program." << endl;
            cin >> letter;
        }

    else
        cout << "Invalid input." << endl;
    } 

    return 0;
    }
   ```

Comment: [`std::toupper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/toupper) takes an `int` as input and will make _one_ character uppercase, You'll have to loop over the characters in your C string and call `toupper` on them individually.

Comment: Casting doesn't work like that. To convert a string to an integer use e.g. [`std::stoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol).

Comment: Also, a string of seven characters needs space for *eight*, to be able to fit the null-terminator. And you have currently no way of preventing buffer overflow. Use `std::string` for all your strings instead.

Comment: I am not sure I follow the logic of your program at all.  I agree with @Someprogrammerdude that you should use std::string and not c strings.  Why are you dividing by three and adding and subtracting? Why convert the input to upper case? Also the static cast is illegal.

Comment: @RichardFeynman It is doing that math because it is a telephone program so typing GOT HAMS should turn to 468-4267

Comment: I will be able to post the errors and assignment details in about 3 hours when I get home from work, sorry in the mean time!

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I tried making phrase into a string, but I don't know how I would convert that into a phone number from there. I just really don't want to write a bunch of case statements....

Comment: @zepholose You need to provide aditional details about what your input and output are.  I had assumed that you were to take a string "123-4567" and convert it to and int, 1234567

Comment: @RichardFeynman, no that is not what I am doing, I actually talked about what I was doing with this code above the coded section, please re-read it as I have added more information!

Comment: Don't store Phone-numbers (or any other number which can contain leading zeros) into integers. Use strings.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude then how would I convert it? When I used string and static cast it didn't allow me because string can't convert to int. How would I then convert it to int??

Comment: You should ***not*** convert to an int. Think of a phone-number like `0436525`. If you convert it to an `int` then it would become `436525`. Notice a difference between the string and the integer? *The leading zero is **missing***. In phone-numbers things like leading zeroes are significant and rather important.

Comment: I hear what you are saying, but that is not what the user would be typing in, they would type in something like, "BuTTER anD ToaST", the target of the program is to take that phrase and convert it to the first seven numbers so "BuTTER a" would change to 288-8372